# Best approach to distribute a python package on a local segregated network

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, github-actions, setuptools

Dear community members,

I would like to have your opinions about my situation. I wrote some python modules to simplify the daily routine at work. I'm the only 'developer' and the user community is a handful of people with limited computer skills. The scripts should be available on several computers (*Windows 7, 10 and 11*) connected on a segregated network with no internet access.

I'm writing the code on a single PC (*Windows 10*) using Anaconda as environment and Spyder as IDE. The scripts are saved on a shared network disk that is accessible from all other PC in the segregated LAN.

And here comes my question: **how should I package and distribute the code on all client PC?**

My **first** idea was to ***not distribute it at all***. I mean, I wanted to leave the code on the shared disk, and let the users double click on a shortcut on the desktop to have it running. The advantage is that I don't have to care about package creation and distribution.
Nevertheless I can see these limitations:

1. I need to install Anaconda on all PCs and, in particular on windows 7, I can only install an old release of it.
2. I need to modify the code in order that user-based configurations are saved on a local file and not on the shared disc.
3. In order to have access to shared modules between scripts, I need to add all relevant paths to the python search path on all PCs.

My **second** approach was to build an exe file for each script with pyinstaller and have them distributed on all clients. I can automatize the build and the copy on all pcs, so that I'm sure that everybody is using the same latest version. The advantage is that I don't need to install Anaconda everywhere but it has some drawbacks:

1. Each exe file is huge. All scripts have a Qt GUI and the size of the *one-file* exe generated by pyinstaller can easily reach 500 MB. This means that when the user double click on the icon, (s)he may have to wait a couple of seconds (depending on the disk speed and caching) before it is loaded and (s)he may thing that the computer is blocked and not working.
2. pyinstaller is multi-platform but not cross-platform. It means that I need to have two other *development* pcs, one with Win 7 and one with Win 11, to generate the exe file.

My **third** possibility was to generate a real python package that can be installed on all PC. And here the tricky point is, should it be installed with **conda** or with **pip**. I have a lot of confusion in mind about package building. I have seen and followed the tutorial on how to build a source and wheel python package on the python [doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), but I don't know if it is the correct approach being my python environment inside anaconda.
I have seen that on git-hub you can automatically build an anaconda package starting from your python code and I would need to read the whole [workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows) documentation on how to do it because it doesn't look so easy to me. The drawback is that the clients PC have no access to GitHub, so I would need to manually copy  the output package from a pc with internet access to somewhere on the segregated net and then let it install on all clients.

So, at the end of this long message, I hope I managed to describe my problem and I'm sure your answers will shed some light on it. I know that the question may sound trivial to the more advanced developers, but there are also newbies out here in need of good advices!

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any kind of python already installed on your co-worker's computer?

Comment: yes, I have created a conda environment clone for each win 10 pc. On the win 7, I still have to do it.